# Monospaced font with smaller spaces

Tags: fonts, monospace

I am looking for a slim Monospaced, serif font where the spaces in between words are smaller than the rest of the characters. Also with medium to smaller size line spacing. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of monospace no?

Comment: @emmet Not entirely - The characters would all be the same width but having the smaller spaces between words would allow for more words on one line

Comment: One alternative would be to use monospace and select all of the spaces afterwards, changing their font size to something smaller

Comment: No, @emmet is right. A designer would not create an entire monospace font *except* for the spaces. It's just that these can be easily adjusted with any design software worth its salt. The other way around would be harder.

Comment: @zach It would be used in Microsoft word and a quick workflow is very important so selecting every space to change size would take a very long time.

Comment: @Thanael You should be able to do them [all at once](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=59105)

Answer (score 4):

Different width spaces kind of defeats the whole point of a monospaced font so I doubt there are many.

It would be easier to either:

1. Edit the width of the spaces of an existing font in a font editor. [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) is a free open source font editor.
2. Change the word-spacing setting of whatever software you are using (most design software or word processors will have some form of word-spacing setting)
3. If you can't change the word-spacing, style the spaces. Either change the font or font size. You could do a search & replace—but you will obviously need to re-do this after any edits so it's not exactly ideal.

**Fonts**

[Newsletter](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typonauten/newsletter/)

[image]

> Monospaced but no mono space.

I havn't checked the metrics myself but this sounds like what you are looking for, and is supposedly designed to be more legible and aesthetic than most monospaced fonts.

Comment: wrt to InDesign: No need for a GREP style. Space width defaults to 100% of the 'native' size but is fully configurable.

Comment: Ah ok, never knew that! Let me check that out for a minute...

Comment: Here you go: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/text-composition.html#change_justification_settings. *Word spacing* has Minimum, Default, and Maximum percentages (these are used in its justification algorithm). Change the Default to a smaller value & you're done.

Comment: Ah yes! Of course you can... duh

Comment: Thinking about it... most software has the ability to change word-spacing. Even MS Word does.

Comment: And the same goes for part 2: line spacing. Oh okay, Windows Notepad cannot control that - but who designs in *Notepad*?

Comment: If i could use a free font editor - would you have any suggestions of a slim, monospace, serif font that is clean and easy to read?

Comment: Added a suggestion to my answer, other than that I would just search some reputable font sites for monospaced fonts. What would be a good font for your situation will depend on a lot of things (that I don't know) :)